# Convert string into node path

Tags: twig, shopware

So i am working on a Shopware shop, and i want to read a MediaEntity in Twig. To do so, i am creating a string with the node path (adding the product ID as a variable), which just works fine.
To actually access the MediaEntity, i need to convert this string into a real node path. How do i do that? Or is there maybe another way to create this path?
Here's my code:

```
{% block component_product_box %}
    {{ parent() }}       
    {% set coverIds = "context.extensions.#{product.coverId}.elements" %}
    {{ dump() }}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/48543281/288568

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access dynamic variable names in twig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697313/how-to-access-dynamic-variable-names-in-twig)

Comment: The information in the both links work only for one "level". Posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it roughly and something like this should work:

```
{% set coverIds = _context['extensions'][product.coverId]['elements'] %}
```

This should solve your problem, I hope.

If you really need to work with a string and "dots" notation, this could be of help:

[How to use Twig's attributed function to access nested object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56153143/how-to-use-twigs-attributed-function-to-access-nested-object-properties)